# Copy some generic questions from meta.SO?

Tags: feature-request

There are quite a few topics that have already been covered, but the new SF user will have no understanding of what the meta.SO site is, much less how to track down some of the fundamental information in questions like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes).

Are we better off starting these topics over again, or getting a copy function going to import some of these gems?

Comment: It could be nice to have this. Instead of a copy, perhaps something symlink *ish*, so continuing discussion does not fork the question and answers across the meta sites?

Comment: I suppose I could just re-ask a pile of questions with the [faq] tag on MSO, but that seems clunky.

Comment: @JScott, +10000 symlink the questions!